# SQL: Show average rating and all comments of a movie in vba

Tags: sql, vba

I would like to retrieve all comments of a movie as well as its average rating when I input the movie ID in the label using VBA user form. I got a SQL statement like this:

```
 "SELECT MOV_COMMENTS, AVG(MOV_RATING)" & _
 "FROM MOVIE" & _
 "WHERE MOV_ID = "' & label1.value & '"" & _
 "GROUP BY MOV_ID"
```

But it shows an error to it. Can someone help me check for the coding? Thanks.

Comment: @zealous I have to group by both mov_id and mov_comments?

Comment: what is the error are you getting?

Comment: @zealous not a group by expression

Answer (score 0):

If `MOV_ID` is numeric, then there is no need for the single quotes. In addition, when you are concatenating the SQL statement together, you need to have spaces - I normally put a space at the end of each line, and the start of the next (double spaces get ignored).

Finally, including `MOV_COMMENTS`, which I assume is a text field doesn't make sense. Do you wish to show all comments for a movie, and the overall average? In which case, you may want to use:

```
    strSQL = "SELECT M.MOV_COMMENTS, " _
        & " (SELECT AVG(M1.MOV_RATING) FROM MOVIE AS M1 WHERE M1.MOV_ID=M.MOV_ID) " _
        & " FROM MOVIE AS M " _
        & " WHERE M.MOV_ID=" & lngMovie
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Space is required between lines. And it should be grouped with MOV_COMMENTS.

```
Sql = "SELECT MOV_COMMENTS, AVG(MOV_RATING)   " & _
 "FROM MOVIE  " & _
 "WHERE MOV_ID = '" & label1.Value & "'  " & _
 "GROUP BY MOV_ID, MOV_COMMENTS   "
```

Comment: Group by MOV_COMMENTS will only show individual MOV_RATING instead of AVG?

Comment: @kerz, I don't know your intentions because I don't know your data, but if you don't group with MOV_COMMENTS, you can't use `SELECT MOV_COMMENTS, AVG (MOV_RATING)`. It get an error.